# Arbitrary Ordering From two fields in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a difficult sort to do.  I need to be able to sort the query results in an arbitrary manner.

Here is the Schema:

```
CREATE  TABLE `Wines` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Vinyard` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Quality` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Sell_By` DATE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );


INSERT INTO `Wines` (`Vinyard`, `Quality`, `Sell_By`) VALUES ('Draper', 'High', '2012-03-22');
INSERT INTO `Wines` (`Vinyard`, `Quality`, `Sell_By`) VALUES ('Draper', 'Medium', '2014-07-16');
INSERT INTO `Wines` (`Vinyard`, `Quality`, `Sell_By`) VALUES ('Draper', 'Medium', '2012-01-01');
INSERT INTO `Wines` (`Vinyard`, `Quality`, `Sell_By`) VALUES ('Becks', 'High', '2014-07-16');
INSERT INTO `Wines` (`Vinyard`, `Quality`, `Sell_By`) VALUES ('Becks', 'Ultra', '2013-02-02');
INSERT INTO `Wines` (`Vinyard`, `Quality`, `Sell_By`) VALUES ('Stevens', 'Crap', '2014-08-16');
INSERT INTO `Wines` (`Vinyard`, `Quality`, `Sell_By`) VALUES ('Stevens', 'Medium', '2014-01-01');
INSERT INTO `Wines` (`Vinyard`, `Quality`, `Sell_By`) VALUES ('Stevens', 'Low', '2013-09-13');
INSERT INTO `Wines` (`Vinyard`, `Quality`, `Sell_By`) VALUES ('Miller', 'Low', '2014-01-01');
```

Now I know I can get a simple sort of Quality (that is not alphabetical) as follows:

```
 SELECT *,
CASE Quality
WHEN 'Ultra' THEN 1
WHEN 'High' THEN 2
WHEN 'Medium' THEN 3
WHEN 'Low' THEN 4
WHEN 'Crap' THEN 5
ELSE 6
END AS myORDER
FROM Wines
ORDER BY myOrder
```

That Gives Me

```
ID  Vinyard Quality Sell_By myORDER
5   Becks   Ultra   2013-02-02  1
1   Draper  High    2012-03-22  2
4   Becks   High    2014-07-16  2
2   Draper  Medium  2014-07-16  3
3   Draper  Medium  2012-01-01  3
7   Stevens Medium  2014-01-01  3
8   Stevens Low 2013-09-13  4
9   Miller  Low 2014-01-01  4
6   Stevens Crap    2014-08-16  5
```

OK So Far so good.  Now the Wrinkle.

I need to move the Medium Quality wines  **and only the Medium quality wines**  Whose Sell by date has passed to the end.  SO the result would be

```
ID  Vinyard Quality Sell_By
5   Becks   Ultra   2013-02-02
1   Draper  High    2012-03-22
4   Becks   High    2014-07-16
2   Draper  Medium  2014-07-16
7   Stevens Medium  2014-01-01
8   Stevens Low 2013-09-13
9   Miller  Low 2014-01-01
6   Stevens Crap    2014-08-16
3   Draper  Medium  2012-01-01  <--Notice this one moved
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ORDER BY Quality = 'Medium' AND Sell_By < CURDATE(), myOrder
```

This will order by both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
order by 
  CASE WHEN Quality = 'Medium' 
    and Sell_By < GETDATE() THEN 0 
    ELSE 1 END, 
  myOrder
```

or move the equivalent case inside myOrder. Quality shouldn't be a text column, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following query:

```
SELECT *,
CASE Quality
WHEN 'Ultra' THEN 1
WHEN 'High' THEN 2
WHEN 'Medium' THEN 3
WHEN 'Low' THEN 4
WHEN 'Crap' THEN 5
ELSE 6
END AS myOrder,
IF(`Quality`='Medium' AND `Sell_By`<NOW(),`Sell_By`,NULL) as `med_sell_by`
FROM Wines
ORDER BY ISNULL(`med_sell_by`) DESC,`med_sell_by` ASC, myOrder ASC;
```

This will return an additional column which, if the `quality` is "medium" and `sell_by` has passed, contains the `sell_by` date for sorting to the bottom. If those criteria are not met, the additional field will be NULL and sorted to the top.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/637e2/9)